# Sharepoint + ASP.NET Website - Encountering "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have an ASP.NET Web Site hosted in the _layouts folder of a SP2010 site.

One of the pages contains a server-side form and works fine until I try to set its master page to a Sharepoint master page (specifically a modified **v4.master**) to achieve a consistent look & feel.

I've placed my original page content within `<asp:content>` tags but it now throws an "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" error. I know that ASP.NET pages can only contain a single server-side form but what walkarounds can I use to stop Sharepoint from throwing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, just delete the form tags in the ASP.NET pages as there is already a server side form within v4.master itself.

The ASP.NET page will then use the form inside the master page happily without complaints :)